# how can I align some text inside a link styled as a button

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, alignment

I made a link that looks like a button, with the same properties in CSS as the button next to it, but for some reason the text is a bit higher in the link that looks like a button... any suggestions?

This are the properties:

```css
.submit,
.btn_advance_search {
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  border: 1px solid #f8f9fa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #3c4043;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 11px 4px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  line-height: 27px;
  height: 36px;
  min-width: 54px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
```

[image: button vs link that looks like a button]

I tried for the link that looks like a button:

```
.btn_advance_search  {
   horiz-align: center;
}
```

without success. I also played with the padding at the top but that makes the actual button bigger...

Comment: Can you please share the HTML structure too?

Comment: `horiz-align` is not a valid property. it does not exist. For flexbox it is called `align-items`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can center align using flex:

```css
.btn_advance_search  {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;

   /* Add if the above styles don't take full height and width */
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%
}
```

Comment: You can even apply these styles to the common class of `search` and `advanced search` buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change the line-height to be the same as the height of the element. Make sure that there isn't any (vertical) padding on the element.

You can try this:

```
line-height: 36px;
height: 36px;
```

Bonus tip: You could also add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your CSS if you want to prevent that the element grows when you add padding to it.

Comment: ohhh many thanks, it works! and thanks for the box-sizing tip, didn't know about that, very useful!! cheers!